# Paradoxes and Classical logic

Tags: logic

Do paradoxes in a sense "break" classical logic due to the law of excluded middle? Since the common example "This statement is false" cannot be a proposition, so when dealing with paradoxes do we require another form of logic, like relevance logic or intuitionist logic? And if so what is the problem with intuitionist logic, causing it not to be used as much as classical logic?

Comment: There are a lot of different paradoxes out there. The Sorites paradox, for example, is pretty different from Zeno's paradoxes, which are pretty different from Russell's paradox. Not sure they can all be treated with the same explanation.

Comment: Intuitionistic logic doesn't resolve the liar's paradox, e.g. it can still prove that $\lnot (p \leftrightarrow \lnot p)$ is a tautology.

Comment: This question is way too vague and broad to have any sort of mathematical answer.

Answer (score 7):

Paradoxes do not break the classical logic. They are simply not considered as  statements. For example "This statement is false" is not a statement because it does not take a truth value.

Answer (score 2):

Classical logic works. It is basis for most if not all of the mathematics so successfully used by scientists and engineers today. Nothing short of proving it inconsistent would displace it from its dominant position. It would certainly take more than nonsensical constructs like "This statement is false." You would need to formally prove a theorem and its negation using *only* the rules of classic logic (FOL).